# Store doesn't trigger reactivity after being updated

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to achieve reactively add nodes to a tree control. I have a Tree control that takes a writable store as a prop. I've created two methods (A,B) for adding nodes to the tree but one is not working at all and the second one is working only partially.

**Method A:**

This method finds a parent node and add node to it. The node is added to the store but it's visible only after reopening the the parent tree.

```js
const addNodeBtnA_OnClick = () => {
    const findNodeByName = (name: string, nodes: TreeNodeInfo[]): TreeNodeInfo | undefined => {          
        for (const node of nodes) {
            if (node.name === name) return node;            
            const foundNode = findNodeByName(name, node.childNodes);
            if (foundNode) return foundNode;
        }  
        return undefined;
    }

    // "state" is the store that's passed to the the Tree component
    state.update(curr => {         
        findNodeByName(parentNodeName, curr)?.childNodes.push({ isRoot: false, name: newChildNodeName, childNodes: []});
        return curr;
    })

    console.log($state); // The store is updated, but reactivity is not triggered at all 
}
```

**Method B:**

This method maps the current state and creates the new one. The node is also added to the store but it's not visible even after reopening the the parent tree. It seems that calling this function messes up the store, because after the call the second method (addNodeBtnB_OnClick) also stops working.

```js
const addNodeBtnB_OnClick = () => {
    const addNode = (parentNodeName: string,
        currentNode: TreeNodeInfo,
        nodeToAdd: TreeNodeInfo) : TreeNodeInfo => {
        return currentNode.name === parentNodeName
          ? { ...currentNode, childNodes: [...currentNode.childNodes, nodeToAdd] }
          : {
              ...currentNode,
              childNodes: currentNode.childNodes.map((node) => addNode(parentNodeName, node, nodeToAdd))
            }
    };

    state.update(
      curr => curr.map((node => addNode(parentNodeName, node, { isRoot: false, name: newChildNodeName, childNodes: []}))
    ));

    console.log($state); 
}
```

Surrounding code and display components:

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
    const treeStructure = [{
        isRoot: true,
        name: "nodeA",
        childNodes: [
            { isRoot: false, name: "nodeB", childNodes: [] },
            { isRoot: false, name: "nodeC", childNodes: [] },
        ],
    }]

    const state = writable(treeStructure);
</script>

<Tree state={state} />
```

```html
<!-- Tree.svelte -->
<script>
    import TreeNode from "./TreeNode.svelte"; 
    export let state;
</script>
  
{#each $state as node}
    <TreeNode nodeInfo={node} />
{/each}
```

```html
<!-- TreeNode.svelte -->
<script>
    export let nodeInfo;
 
    let isOpen = true;
    let childNodes = nodeInfo.childNodes;
    $: nodeState = isOpen ? "(opened)" : "(closed)";
 
    const toggleIsOpen = () => (isOpen = !isOpen);
 </script>
 
 <div class="node-container">
    <div class="parent-node">
       {#if !nodeInfo.isRoot}
          <div class="connection-container">
             <div class="connection" />
          </div>
       {/if}
          
        <button on:click={toggleIsOpen}>
            {`${nodeInfo.name} ${nodeState}`}
        </button>
    </div>
 
    {#if isOpen}
       <div class="child-nodes">
          {#each childNodes as childNode}
             <svelte:self nodeInfo={childNode} />
          {/each}
       </div>
    {/if}
 </div>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/eea7bd74f5a74f6d817c0c2db48ed593?version=4.2.2)

**Could anyone explain to me:**

a) *What's wrong with the Method A?*

b) *How to make node visible without need of reopening its parent node?*

Comment: Hard to know without the code that is rendering/using the tree. You should not try to just deploy **everything**, create a minimal example from scratch, ideally right in the REPL and then add *all* code to the question, which should not be that much at that point. Having a link to some repository is not sufficient.

Comment: I didn't try to upload everything, this is the minimalistic version I've created from the scratch, the original is much bigger. I've tried codesandbox.io, playcode.io and even REPL, but non of these don't "digest" the 'lightweight" solution.

Comment: I don't see any reason why they could not. What is the problem?

Comment: On REPL I get this message: "Cannot access the file system (via "path.resolve") when using the browser build of Rollup. Make sure you supply a plugin with custom resolveId and load hooks to Rollup". I'll update my question with the link to REPL, but I can't guarantee that the solution will be working.

Comment: There are errors because there is still junk. There are imports from `"./TreeNodeInfo"`, which does not exist. There is a `Writable` import that is a type-only import, which will not work. And there is still TS syntax on `toggleIsOpen` (type annotation). If you fix all that it will run just fine.

Comment: Mbad, I was converting the solution from ts to js at pace. Now it's fixed. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255758/discussion-between-olafvolafka-and-h-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one problem and it has nothing to do with the functions, this line:

```js
// TreeNode.svelte
let childNodes = nodeInfo.childNodes;
```

Either make that reactive (`$: ...`) or inline it in the markup, otherwise the children are just read once and never again.

If this is fixed, both methods work just fine.

The reason why the method that uses mapping works *less* without the fix, is that the components keep referencing objects that are no longer in the store, so they are never updated at all.

Comment: Now it's working. Thank you for the fix and for the explanation what was the cause of the issue.